# como hacer un join sin duplicar registros

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tardes como podria obtener el siguiente resultado de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en sql server ya que tengo 3 tablas de las cuales 2 heredan de una principal, pero al hacer un join entre estas tablas me duplica el valor

Comment: ya probaste agregando distinct a tu consulta para evitar que te devuelva valores duplicados

Comment: pero sobre todo agrega el código que haz intentado

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado de momento? ¿Has probado a utilizar [DISTINCT](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187831(v=sql.105).aspx) o [GRUOP BY](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189288(v=sql.90).aspx)?

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Porque ese valor no deberia duplicarse, si por logica el join lo resuelve como corresponde?

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza `LEFT JOIN` de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLA1
     LEFT JOIN TABLA2 ON TABLA1.id_tabla1 = TABLA2.id_tabla1
     LEFT JOIN TABLA3 ON TABLA1.id_tabla1 = TABLA3.id_tabla1
```

Lo que hace es que te regresa todos los registros de la tabla de la izquierda (TABLA1) y pega a la derecha todos los registros de la segunda tabla **que cumplan con la condición**, la condición se pone después del **ON**. Como en todas las tablas haces referencia al ID de la tabla 1, utilicé ese ID.

Como puedes ver, se pueden ir anexando varias tablas usando éste tipo de JOIN.

Qué pasa cuando no se cumple la condición? Los registros se quedan como nulos. Tal y como aparece tu resultado deseado en la imagen que compartiste.

Comment: es ideal esperar a responder hasta que el OP agrega código que ha intentado, lo que ha obtenido y lo que espera obtener

Comment: Concuerdo en que debe mostrarse un esfuerzo de parte del OP. Sé que no es una página de "háganme el trabajo". Pero en éste caso creo que con su imagen y el texto se entiende cuál es el problema, qué está usando (un JOIN), qué obtiene, y qué espera.  Para mí, si está utilizando una herramienta incorrecta/no tan apropiada, realmente no me ayuda cómo la está utilizando. Mejor le indico cuál es la mejor manera, y le explico cómo se hace. Si por mero trámite o regla se debe esperar a que el OP ponga su código, me esperaré de ahora en adelante.

Comment: Es que tampoco tu respuesta resuelve el problema, mira bien la imagen y te darás cuenta que no es un tema que se resuelva mediante un JOIN.

Comment: Para dejar mas en claro, hay varios puntos que estan mal en la pregunta. Se esta tratando de solucionar un problema de vista con una consulta y no se esta aclarando la logica para la no repeticion (no se porque no deberia repetirse, haga el join que haga)